# How can I track down why my activity gets finished?

Tags: java, android

*Context*

I'm one of the developers working on a pretty large and very complicated project. Half of the project is written with JavaScript and the other half with Java, moreover about 30% of the base product comes to us pre-compiled, so we cannot exactly look inside or debug through it.

*Problem*

When our application comes back to foreground the activities stack gets destroyed and only the root activity is displayed. I cannot track down why.

*Things I've tried so far*

1. Setting a breakpoint on every finish() call I could find, none of them gets called
2. Setting android:excludeFromRecents="false" to every activity
3. Removing android:launchMode="singleTop" from the AndroidManifest
4. I've set a breakpoint in onDestroy() method for the second activity and I can see that "isFinishing()" method is executed to "True", so I know that it is not the OS that is destroying the activity, but there is no information (as far as I can see) which would pinpoint me to which class/property/method caused the method to be called. There is nothing usefully I can see in the stack trace. There is nothing useful I can see in the logs.
5. I've also tried asking people around in my company, but no answer this far.

*Question*

Are there any strategies to find what caused a certain lifecycle method to be called?

**Update 1**

Thank you for the great questions and the help in the comments section. Here is the sequence diagram to explain better what is happening.

1. *Application is launched*
2. Activity A calls onCreate()
3. Activity A calls onResume()
4. *I launch Activity B*
5. Activity A calls onUserLeaveHint()
6. Activity A calls onPause()
7. Activity B calls onCreate()
8. Activity B calls onResume()
9. Activity A calls onStop()
10. *I put the application into the background*
11. Activity B calls onUserLeaveHint()
12. Activity B calls onStop()
13. *I return the application to foreground*
14. **Activity B calls onDestroy()**
15. Activity A calls onRestart()
16. Activity A calls onResume()

**Update 2**

Here are the screenshots of the memory usage

When I launch the application
[image]

When I launch Activity B

[image]

When I send the application to the background

[image]

When I return to foreground

[image]

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/square/leakcanary to track if you have a memory leak?

Comment: @Gatunox, thank you for the suggestion. I did not look into memory leaks yet. The behaviour is very consistent, so I doubt it would be a memory leak. Activity gets destroyed every time the application returns to the foreground.

Comment: That could happen either because phone is waking up from sleep or application is returned from the background. And it doesn't matter how long application spent in the background (5 seconds or two minutes).

Comment: I'm almost certain that there is some "finish()" call hidden somewhere where I cannot see.

Comment: Check the following methods if you have them: onPause(), onStop(), onDestroy(), onUserLeaveHint(), onRestart(). You may notice something wrong in them... Also if you are certain that finish() is called somewhere, then try to search for it in your whole project. That might help.

Comment: So basically it happens every time you go to background?

Comment: So my other idea is to check the memory, do you know how much memory is the app using? have you check it on DDMS when debugin?

Comment: @HusseinElFeky, thank you for your comment. I've updated the question to reflect the sequence of the calls. Everything seems logical to me aside from the step 14.

Comment: Is it possible that configuration changed (orientation or something else) and OS decide to recreate activities?

Comment: Is there any call of onBackPressed() in onPause/onStop?

Comment: @Gatunox, I've just uploaded screenshots from DDMS, I can't see a large spike in memory usage.

Comment: @tse, thank you for the suggestion. I've tried to set a breakpoint on every onBackPressed() call I could find, but none of them gets called.

Comment: @tse, I don't think that configuration change is happening. I'm running the app in portrait and my home screen activity is also in portrait. In any case, onCreate doesn't get called after I return to foreground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And the solution is found!

Turns out that my root activity had the following property set:

```
android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
```

Here is a quote from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#clear):

> android:clearTaskOnLaunch 
>   Whether or not all activities will be
>   removed from the task, except for the root activity, whenever it is
>   re-launched from the home screen — "true" if the task is always
>   stripped down to its root activity, and "false" if not. The default
>   value is "false". This attribute is meaningful only for activities
>   that start a new task (the root activity); it's ignored for all other
>   activities in the task. When the value is "true", every time users
>   start the task again, they are brought to its root activity regardless
>   of what they were last doing in the task and regardless of whether
>   they used the Back or Home button to leave it. When the value is
>   "false", the task may be cleared of activities in some situations (see
>   the alwaysRetainTaskState attribute), but not always.
>
> Suppose, for example, that someone launches activity P from the home
>   screen, and from there goes to activity Q. The user next presses Home,
>   and then returns to activity P. Normally, the user would see activity
>   Q, since that is what they were last doing in P's task. However, if P
>   set this flag to "true", all of the activities on top of it (Q in this
>   case) were removed when the user pressed Home and the task went to the
>   background. So the user sees only P when returning to the task.
>
> If this attribute and allowTaskReparenting are both "true", any
>   activities that can be re-parented are moved to the task they share an
>   affinity with; the remaining activities are then dropped, as described
>   above.

And here is a great article which helped me to find it: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work:

```
@Override
public void finish() {
   super.finish();
   Log.d("derp", "who is calling me?", new RuntimeException());
}
```

Comment: Ah, that's a clever trick! Unfortunately, finish() isn't called. If I press the back button while inside of the activity, then "finish()" is called, but not when I bring the application back to the foreground.

Comment: Interesting, I suppose that means that there is no explicit call to finish() method. But what is it then? :)